# Express - res.download not working correctly

Tags: node.js, express

So I'm attempting to download a file in the server which I get and place in my current directory and when I try to send it back to the user using res.download(file) it seems to send it as plain text instead of sending an attachment to download. I'm currently trying to send a .doc file.
http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.download

I have tried to set the headers res.setHeaders('Content-Disposition', 'attachment') but that doesn't seem to work either.

variable file currently has the path to the file exactly.

```
var file = path.join(__dirname, result)

res.download(file, result, function(err){
  if(err){
      console.log("err", err)
  }
})
```

Comment: Check the headers of the response on the browser. Maybe the headers are not set properly.

Comment: headers seems to not be set correctly. I have tried. res.download and res.attachment but doesn't seem to work. I just tried now res.sendFile and the headers seem to be correct now  saying the content-type is application/mssword which is correct but its still sending it as text and now downloading the file...

Comment: Are you requesting the download-URL from a JS script?